# Android.mk paths for external libs

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android.mk

I am working on an Android Native project using a couple of libraries (e.g OpenCV) that are not going to be pushed to the repository, mainly due to their size - instead they will be downloaded separately.

I am currently linking them my giving an absolute path in my system, which is clearly not a great thing for anyone else who wants to use the project. Linking them relatively doesn't seem like a great option either, since it's improbable that anyone would use the exact same relative location.

Apart from documenting the project well and indicating where do contributors need to change paths in order to compile the project - what's the best thing to do to ensure my project can be built as out of the box as possible?

Comment: _"mainly due to their size"_ How big are we talking? Unless you've got several gigabytes worth of libraries I don't see why it would be an issue. Especially if they're not going to be modified often.

Comment: Android OpenCV for example is 400MB - I just feel like generally there isn't any real reason to add in this kind of libraries - also OpenCV gets updated quite a lot with bugfixes and all that. OpenCV_contrib is about 100MB as well